# Interaction between taskset and sched_setaffinity

Tags: linux, affinity

Could anyone tell me what would occur if I ran

```
taskset -c 7 ./fred.x
```

but then inside `fred.x` a thread is calling `sched_setaffinity` to bind to core 6?

Would that thread get ANY cpu time ever, or will it remain idle indefinitely?

Comment: I swear I should write a script that picks up new posts and changes or reformats random selections. I mean, 3 minutes is hardly a fast turnaround. It's like people aren't even watching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`taskset` itself calls `sched_setaffinity()` and then `execve` to run your command.  So this question boils down to "What happens if I call `sched_setaffinity()` twice in the same thread?"  And the answer is, the second call overrides the first.

So in your specific example, the thread which calls `sched_setaffinity()` will indeed be bound to core 6, and it will be runnable.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. It's my understanding that taskset affects the process and sched_setaffinity affects threads. As long as you're assuring me that having two non-overlapping core affinities for these two things can't happen, you get the points!

Comment: `taskset` just calls `sched_setaffinity()` for you.  It "affects the process" because when your program starts it has exactly one thread.  What you do in your program afterward is none of `taskset`'s concern, nor can it be, because once `taskset` calls `execve`, the `taskset` code is no longer running--your process is.